# I've problems using the console in python

Tags: python, console

I'm trying to practice a new programming language and I've a problem with this script:

```
num1 = 10

num2 = 5

print(num1 + num2)
print(num1 - num2)
print(num1 * num2)
print(num1 / num2)
print(num1 // num2)
print(num1 ** num2)
print(num1 % num2)

suma = num1 + num2

print(suma)
```

when i use the console don't give me the answer `(num1 + num2)`

it said that there's a problem but I think it´s ok [here's the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Vrv.png)

I can't found a solution. please, help me!!

Comment: switch to Output

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the mathematical output?
If so, it will be displayed in the 'OUTPUT' tab, not the 'TERMINAL' tab.
The terminal will only show logs.

If you have checked the 'OUTPUT' tab and still haven't received an answer, it's possible that you don't have the correct interpreter installed or configure on PyCharm.